# How to set the PYTHONSTARTUP in Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to set the PYTHONSTARTUP Python Environment Variables

All what in known is the PYTHONSTARTUP

It contains the path of an initialization file containing Python source code.

It is executed every time you start the interpreter. It is named as .

pythonrc.py in Unix and it contains commands that load utilities or modify PYTHONPATH.

But how to set in Windows 7 and what is the value

Comment: [Windows Environment Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx)...

Comment: But what is the write value PYTHONSTARTUP

Comment: A path to whatever startup script you want to execute? It's not required, you know...

Comment: Thanks for your reply  